# How the brain would recover by itself?

Tags: brain, recovery, brain-damage, coma-comatose

After reading [this story about Terry Wallis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terry_Wallis) and how his brain worked to self recovery, what are the medical/scientific conclusions and theories that we can collect from his medical status and what we can do for future discoveries ?

---

**The summary of the story:**

> He was in a Coma for 19 years and doctors said to family that he will not recover at all. 
>   But suddenly, he regained consciousness and was able to speak.

Comment: Please provide a link that is *not* a click-baiting time waster. Or even better: expand your question with a summary of what is found on that site.

Comment: I edited your question for the reason @LangLangC pointed out. The article you linked to was pure click bait. I'm not willing to read an article presented one paragraph per page, so I replaced it with a Wikipedia summary.

Comment: @CareyGregory see the edited question

Comment: @LangLangC see the edited question

Comment: I'd love to see a good answer for this but I'm afraid I don't think you'll get one because I don't think anyone really understands how this happens. It's very rare, so that makes it very hard to study.

Comment: It's called neuroplasticity, the ability of unused, or previously used areas of the brain to take over new functions.  And the recognition that neural progenitor cells can be activated in the CNS https://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/763955